# AnchorLink Styling

Tags: reactjs, typescript, hyperlink, tailwind-css

I am using the AnchorLink component from "react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll"
I want to sytles this component using Tailwind css by adding styles to className.

```
import React from "react";
import AnchorLink from "react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll";
import { SelectedPage } from "./types";

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  setSelectedPage: (value: SelectedPage) => void;
};

const ActionButton = ({ children, setSelectedPage }: Props) => {
  return (
    <AnchorLink
      onClick={() => setSelectedPage(SelectedPage.ContactUs)}
      href={`#${SelectedPage.ContactUs}`}
      className="rounded-md bg-secondary-500 px-10 py-2 hover:bg-primary-500 hover:text-white"
    >
      {children}
    </AnchorLink>
  );
};

export default ActionButton;
```

But the styles are not appling.
How do we add styles to this component?

Comment: Consider checking that the file the code is in is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration.

Comment: tailwind.config.js file should contain the following things `@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;` and styling file should having the naming **index.css** mostly by default is 'styles.css'